# Does subgit support multiple 'branches' directories?

Tags: subgit

Does subgit support multiple 'branches' directories?

For example, if one had an SVN repo that went like:

```
trunk/...
branches/<branch>/...
releases/<release>/...
tags/<tag>/...
```

but "releases" was really just release branches.

We would want both "branches/" and "releases/" in SVN to become branches in Git.

And if a new branch was created in Git, then in SVN we would want a new directory in "branches/" (i.e. "releases/" is deprecated).

So what we want is multiple branch mappings, but with with one of them being the "primary" one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since version 2.0 you can specify 'branches' option in SubGit config several times. There's a restriction: left and right parts of the patterns should not intersect or be the same (otherwise the rules become ambiguous):

```
trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
branches = releases/*:refs/heads/releases/*
shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

You can't map `releases/*` and `branches/*` to `refs/heads/*` simultaneously, because this makes rules ambiguous (in this case SubGit doesn't know, whether to map `refs/heads/branch` to `branches/branch` or to `releases/branch`).