# How to import tags from multiple folders?

Tags: subgit

I successfully executed `subgit import` on large old repository.
Later i discovered, that there were two directories for tags: default `tags` and `tag`.

I tried to edit subgit config file according to advices in [Does subgit support multiple 'branches' directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219978/does-subgit-support-multiple-branches-directories)

Currently i have tags configured the following way:'

```
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
tags = tag/*:refs/tags/tag/*
```

But now when i try to execute import command again, Subgit does nothing, like everything seems to be already up to date. What i did wrong or i need to run `subgit import` from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you have to start importing from scratch. You can run

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url SVN_URL repo.git
```

Then edit repo.git/subgit/config to specify

```
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
tags = tag/*:refs/tags/tag/*
```

Then

```
$ subgit install repo.git
```

and finally

```
$ subgit uninstall repo.git
```

to stop continuous synchronization. You can also use "subgit import" command as a shortcut for "subgit install" + "subgit uninstall".

As a bonus you'll have all SVN revision numbers saved in refs/svn/map reference. To see revision numbers in "git log" output you can setup you Git clients as it is recommended in [SubGit book](https://subgit.com/remote-book.html#20) or run the following command on the server:

```
$ git update-ref refs/notes/commits refs/svn/map
```

Comment: I mapped my tags in this way: `tags = tag/*:refs/tags/*;tags = tags/*:refs/tags/tags/*`, now i noticed that for tags from svn's `tags` folder Subgit created orphan nameless branch. While tags from svn's `tag` folder were set on commits in `master` branch. Why could this happen? Is it a bug or i could do something wrong?

Comment: Orphan branch can be created if a directory from which it was created is not mapped to Git branches/tags. I don't understand what you mean by nameless, could you please drop me a line to support@subgit.com and send "svn log -v " output for the revision where the tag from `tags` is created.